# What can I do to help bring a refuah shlema to a relative in critical condition?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

A family member just got into a car accident (please pray for the refuah shlemah of Tang Jing bas Huai Jun). She is in critical condition, having her head injured. What is the best thing I can do to tilt her toward life? Tehilim? Teshuva?

I notice my sister and I have a very similar relationship between her and my father, they are also older brothers and younger sisters? My sister also began experiencing headaches and chest pains around the time of the accident. Does Kabbalah say anything about helping  one side of two seemingly connected neshamos?

Comment: related: [prayer for someone undergoing surgery](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30085/prayer-for-someone-undergoing-surgery/30087#30087)

Comment: Yasher koach. Thank you. May you and yours be blessed with  perfect health.

Comment: Those are two different questions. Please post the Kabbalah part as a separate one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prayer for someone undergoing surgery](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30085/prayer-for-someone-undergoing-surgery)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28406/759

Comment: @Al This is broader than just prayer, asking for other things to help them as well. Voting to leave open.

Comment: May Tang Jing experience a complete recovery! I agree with DonielF that the first half of this post is broader than the previous post and therefore not a duplicate. I agree with AlBerko that the second paragraph is a distinct question. Please [edit] it out and consider posting it as a separate question. Finally, this post, as currently written, sounds like it's requesting advice for your particular situation, which is advice that Mi Yodeya [is not equipped to offer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). A rabbi who knows you and your family would be best-placed to offer such advice.

Answer (score 3):

These are two different questions, I will address the first one. Prayer is a recognized way of asking Hashem for healing. See [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1228223/jewish/Psalms-and-Jewish-Prayer-for-Healing.htm) and [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/809299/jewish/Psalms-for-Times-of-Distress.htm) for a list and the content of Tehilim (Psalms) for healing and in times of distress. You can also ask friends and family members to do the same (I did it already).

Also you can add her name in the *Refaeinu* blessing of Shmonei Esrei, your siddur should have the relevant addition to pray for sick people.

Giving charity in the merit of the family member is also a good idea.

May Hashem send Tang Jing bas Huai Jun a quick and complete recovery.